# Pass struct by reference in C

Tags: c, struct

Is this code correct? It runs as expected, but is this code correctly using the pointers and dot notation for the struct?

```
struct someStruct {
 unsigned int total;
};

int test(struct someStruct* state) {
 state->total = 4;
}

int main () {
 struct someStruct s;
 s.total = 5;
 test(&s);
 printf("\ns.total = %d\n", s.total);
}
```

Comment: why is test supposed to return an int ? actually there is not return there.

Comment: C does have references? Suprised ...

Comment: @honk: not in the C++ sense, but before C++ was invented, pointers were a kind of "reference" (because they have a "referand"). Now they have a "pointee" or some such nonsense. Since `someStruct` has value semantics, "pass-by-reference" (which C doesn't do in C++ terms) is exactly the same thing as "passing a reference by value" (which it does, the "reference" in question being a pointer).

Comment: c++ references (declared with the ampersand token) are superior in that: 1) It is less likely to write a bug with a c++ reference, and 2) code written with c++ references is more likely to enable the compiler to make aliasing optimizations.  Since aliasing is impossible in fortran, unoptimized pointer routines in c can cause embarassment.

Answer (score 68):

Your use of pointer and dot notation is good.  The compiler should give you errors and/or warnings if there was a problem.

Here is a copy of your code with some additional notes and things to think about so far as the use of structs and pointers and functions and scope of variables.

**Note:** A code writing difference in the source example below is I put a space after the struct name and before the asterisk in the function definition/declaration as in `struct some_struct *p1;` and the OP put a space after the asterisk as in `struct some_struct* p1;`. There is no difference to the compiler, just a readability and habit difference for the programmer. I prefer putting the asterisk next to the variable name to make clear the asterisk changes the variable name it is next to. This is especially important if I have more than one variable in a declaration or definition. Writing `struct some_struct *p1, *p2, var1;` will create two pointers, `p1` and `p2`, and a variable, `var1`. Writing `struct some_struct* p1, p2, var1;` will create single pointer, `p1` and two variables `p2` and `var1`

```
// Define the new variable type which is a struct.
// This definition must be visible to any function that is accessing the
// members of a variable of this type.
struct some_struct {
    unsigned int total;
};

/*
 * Modifies the struct that exists in the calling function.
 *   Function test() takes a pointer to a struct some_struct variable
 *   so that any modifications to the variable made in the function test()
 *   will be to the variable pointed to.
 *   A pointer contains the address of a variable and is not the variable iteself.
 *   This allows the function test() to modify the variable provided by the
 *   caller of test() rather than a local copy.
 */
int test(struct some_struct *state) {
    state->total = 4;
    return 0;
}

/* 
 * Modifies the local copy of the struct, the original
 * in the calling function is not modified.
 * The C compiler will make a copy of the variable provided by the
 * caller of function test2() and so any changes that test2() makes
 * to the argument will be discarded since test2() is working with a
 * copy of the caller's variable and not the actual variable.
 */
int test2(struct some_struct state) {
    state.total = 8;
    return 0;
}

/*
 * Make a local copy of the argument then modify the local copy.
 * Until the assignment of the local copy to the argument is made,
 * the changes to the local copy are not made to the argument.
 * To make any changes made to the local copy in the argument,
 * you need to assign the local copy to the argument.
 */
int test3(struct some_struct *state) {
    struct some_struct state_copy;
    state_copy = *state;    // make a local copy of the struct
    state_copy.total = 12;  // modify the local copy of the struct
    *state = state_copy;    /* assign the local copy back to the original in the
                              calling function. Assigning by dereferencing pointer. */
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    struct some_struct s;

    /* Set the value then call a function that will change the value. */
    s.total = 5;
    test(&s);
    printf("after test(): s.total = %d\n", s.total);

    /*
     * Set the value then call a function that will change its local copy 
     * but not this one.
     */
    s.total = 5;
    test2(s);
    printf("after test2(): s.total = %d\n", s.total);

    /* 
     * Call a function that will make a copy, change the copy,
       then put the copy into this one.
     */
    test3(&s);
    printf("after test3(): s.total = %d\n", s.total);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the significance of putting the "\*" before name of the variable (as is done in this post) or after the type name (as is done by the OP)?


HERE:
    int test(struct someStruct \*state)

OP:
    int test(struct someStruct\* state)

Comment: @ALM the asterisk indicates when specifying the type for a variable indicates that it is a pointer to that type of variable. So `someStruct state` is a variable that is of type `someStruct` however `someStruct *state` is a pointer to a variable of type `someStruct`. See [Pointer Basics](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/).

Comment: Appreciate your response; however, my question was not what the * is for, my question was WHAT IS SIGNIFICANCE OF HAVING THE * (a) after the typename of the struct and (b) having it before the assigned name of struct. i hope that made my questin clearer.

Comment: @ALM, sorry but your clarification does not clarify. Not sure what you mean by "assigned name of struct".  Perhaps you mean that I put a space after the struct name in the declaration and the OP put a space after the name? There is no difference to the compiler, just a readability and habit difference. I prefer putting the asterisk next to the variable name because if I have more than one variable in a declaration. `struct someStruct *p1, *p2, var1;` will create two pointers and a variable. `struct someStruct* p1, p2, var1;` will create single pointer, `p1` and two variables `p2` and var1`.

Comment: yes. Thats exactly what i asked. Many thanks for clearing that out

Comment: When should one use the style of `test`, and when the style of `test3`?

Comment: @Dave The function `test3()` was just to show the difference between making changes to a local copy of the `struct` versus modifying the `struct` that was passed to the function. The important bit in the function `test3()` is that modifying a local copy does not modify the argument. The function also shows how to modify a local copy and then once all changes are made to assign the local copy to the argument thereby changing the value of the argument. In most cases if you are going to modify the argument, you would do it as in `test()` rather than `test3()`.

Comment: @RichardChambers Thanks for the additional explanations! Then I will do it in the style of `test()` from now on, unless there are problem-specific good reasons for `test3()`.

Answer (score 15):

That's correct usage of the struct. There are questions about your return values.

Also, because you are printfing a unsigned int, you should use `%u` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's right. It makes a struct `s`, sets its total to 5, passes a pointer to it to a function that uses the pointer to set the total to 4, then prints it out. `->` is for members of pointers to structs and `.` is for members of structs. Just like you used them.

The return values are different though. `test` should probably be void, and `main` needs a `return 0` at its end.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. It's correct. If it wasn't (from the . / -> point of view), your compiler would yell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its correct usage of structures. You can also use

```
typedef struct someStruct {
 unsigned int total;
} someStruct;
```

Then you won't have to write  `struct someStruct s;` again and again but can use `someStruct s;` then.