# Problem passing a struct by reference in C

Tags: c, reference, struct

I've tried to get my question answered at CProgramming Forums, but they're having some issues with their database.

I have these structs:

```
typedef struct QuadImageInfo *QuadImage;

typedef struct QuadImageInfo
{
    float whiteness;
    QuadImage nw, ne, sw, se;
} QuadImageInfo;
```

I have these functions:

```
void LoadQuadImageAux(FILE *fp, QuadImage img)
{
    int pos;
    QuadImage ptr[4], loaded = NewQuadImage(0.0);
    SetPointersToQuadrants(&img, ptr);

    for(pos = 0; pos < 4; pos++)
    {
        switch(fgetc(fp))
        {
            case '0' : ptr[pos] = NewBlackQuadImage(); break;
            case '1' : ptr[pos] = NewWhiteQuadImage(); break;
            case 'Q' : LoadQuadImageAux(fp, ptr[pos] = loaded);
        }
}

QuadImage LoadQuadImage(FILE *fp)
{
    QuadImage loaded = NewQuadImage(0.0);

    switch(fgetc(fp))
    {
        case '0' : loaded = NewBlackQuadImage(); break;
        case '1' : loaded = NewWhiteQuadImage(); break;
        case 'Q' : LoadQuadImageAux(fp, loaded);
    }

    return loaded;
}
```

As you can see, I create a `QuadImage loaded` in `LoadQuadImage` and I pass it to `LoadQuadImageAux`. My objective is to access/modify the 4 inner QuadImages of `loaded` and then return it in `LoadQuadImage`.
There is a simple way, that consists in "repeating" code 4 times (one for each QuadImage).
I thought of creating an array of pointers to those 4 QuadImages, and access/modify them through the `for loop` in `LoadQuadImageAux`.
The code to generate the `QuadImage pointers array` is:

```
void SetPointersToQuadrants(QuadImage *img, QuadImage *ptr)
{
    ptr[0] = (*img)->nw;
    ptr[1] = (*img)->ne;
    ptr[2] = (*img)->sw;
    ptr[3] = (*img)->se;
}
```

But, for some unknown reason (to me), `loaded` always finishes being `NewQuadImage(0.0)` (it means it is not being modified).

Compiling code [here](http://pastebin.com/SXfLFTvh).

To run this `compiling code` create a file called `1.qad` with the content `Q00Q11111`.
If the program prints `Q00Q11111` at the end, it means it is working.

Thank you `dmckee`, for helping me formatting my post.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A couple of points. First the editor has a code formatting option which is generally preferred to pointing to offsite code. Second, we don't actually like to see a hundred lines of code accompanying a *"It doesn't work"* post. Third, we rather expect you to have done a bit more work: what have *you* done toward understanding the problem? Have you tried writing a minimal hardcoded version to see if you snippet? Is this actually a request for help with debugging technique?

Comment: By a "minimal example" in the above comment I mean something more like the code see in [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4316314/2509). Notice how we do not have to wade through a bunch of extraneous function in search of the part of the code that isn't working? Makes life easier for the people you would like to help you.

Comment: `QuadImageInfo` appears 3 times in those struct definitions. My head just exploded.

Comment: lol @missingno . It isn't relevant to my problem solution though. :b

Comment: If the program isn't printing `Q00Q11111`, then what *is* it doing?

Comment: @John Bode - printing '0' because of this:
`But, for some unknown reason (to me), loaded always finishes being NewQuadImage(0.0) (it means it is not being modified).`

Comment: What does the call `SetPointersToQuadrants(&img, ptr)` do to the `img` argument?  If it `img` is being changed, that change won't be reflected to the caller of `LoadQuadImageAux()`

Comment: The objective of `SetPointersToQuadrants(&img, ptr)`is to make the `ptr array` to point to the `nw, ne, sw and se QuadImages` of `img`.

I want `ptr[0]->whiteness = 0.0` to be equivalent to `img->nw->whiteness = 0.0`

Comment: @shokkapic: jeez - sorry, I just noticed that `SetPointersToQuadrants()` was in the question.  I need to get more sleep (rather, I need to wakeup and pay more attention).

Comment: I would like to see your implementation of NewQuadImage()

Comment: @karlphillip: Compiling code : http://pastebin.com/SXfLFTvh

To run this `compiling code` create a file called `1.qad` with the content `Q00Q11111`.
If the program prints `Q00Q11111` at the end, it means it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In `LoadQuadImageAux`, basically you are doing this:

```
ptr[0] = img->nw;
  //these are now two separate pointers that point to the same location

ptr[0] = NewBlackQuadImage();
  //this changes the location pointed to by ptr[0]
  //it doesn't change the location pointed to by img->nw
  //and it doesn't change the contents of the location pointed to by img->nw
```

You're looping around and changing the pointer values held in the `ptr` array, but you're never making an actually change to the struct that was passed in by reference.

I think what you are trying to do is simply:

```
img->nw = NewBlackQuadImage();
```

and your use of the `ptr` array (presumably to try to make the loop easier to code) is causing confusion.

My advice is to dispense with `ptr` entirely and figure out how to write the code to use the `img` pointer correctly.

Comment: That's what I am doing now. But I repeat code 4 times per function.
And that's what I want to avoid.