# Should I put & while passing a struct?

Tags: c++, struct

The code below is passing the struct variable:

```
struct someStruct {
    unsigned int total;
};

int test(struct someStruct* state) {
    state->total = 4;
}

int main () {
    struct someStruct s;
    s.total = 5;
    test(&s);
    printf("\ns.total = %d\n", s.total);
}
```

(The source from [Pass struct by reference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316314/pass-struct-by-reference-in-c)
)

While programming in C++ may I pass this structure without `&`? I mean

```
test(s); // or should test(&s);
```

Will `s` be copied if I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you can make the function take a reference as parameter:

```
int test(someStruct& state) {
    state.total = 4;
}
```

You can call the function like that:

```
someStruct s;
test(s);
```

No copy will be made. Inside the function, `state` will behave like it was `s`. Note that the `struct` keyword is only required when declaring the struct in C++. Also, in C++ your printing code should look like this:

```
std::cout << "s.total = " << s.total << std::endl;
```

You have to include `iostream` for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a pointer or pass by reference when  you want to change the contents of the structure you are passing to a function, otherwise the function will modify the local copy being created.

You can either **pass a pointer**:

```
int test(struct someStruct* state);
```

or **pass by reference**

```
int test(struct someStruct &state);
```

In both the cases no copy will be created & original structure will be modified.
Important to note passing by reference is a more C++ way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
test(&s);
```

pasess a pointer-to-s. You would use this in the function you currently have defined which accepts a pointer:

```
int test(struct someStruct* state)
```

If you wanted to pass by reference you would change the function definition to

```
int test(struct someStruct& state)
```

and simply call:

```
test(s)
```

and in test you would change your code to use `.` instead of `->`